# Change font-size for table column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a table that is optimized with Bootstrap and I encounter the following problem I want column 1 both header and body to have font size 12px then column number 2 both header and body to have font size 21px.

In other words, I want to customize the font as I want for each column.

Code:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th style="font-size: 12px;">1</th>
        <th style="font-size: 21px;">2</th>
        <th style="font-size: 12px;">3</th>
        <th style="font-size: 21px;">4</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `nth-child/nth-of-type` and if you want a zebra style (column-based) you can use `odd` and `even`

```css
/*one approach */
.table th:first-child,
.table td:first-child {
  font-size: 21px
}

.table th:nth-child(2),
.table td:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 12px
}

/*second approach */

/* odd */
.table th:nth-child(2n+1),
.table td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: red
}

/* even */
.table th:nth-child(2n),
.table td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use odd and even keywords with nth-child:

```css
th:nth-child(odd),
td:nth-child(odd){
  font-size: 12px;
}
th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even){
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Easily with CSS `nth-child` you can target what ever child you want, see below:

```css
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(3){
  font-size: 12px
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(4){
  font-size: 21px
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Check [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) for more about `nth-child`